# Why PHP file handler doesn't work properly?

Tags: php, file, fseek, splfileobject

I have this content on 'test.txt' file: **lucas**

I want to seek pointer in the file and override info ahead. Supposed I do:

```
$f = new SplFileObject('test.txt', 'a');

$f->fseek(-5, SEEK_END);

var_dump($f->ftell());

$f->fwrite('one');
```

This should produce: **oneas** But the result of execution: **lucasone**

I'm crazy about the code logic or even doesn't works?

How is the right way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

You opened the file for appending:

```
$f = new SplFileObject('test.txt', 'a');
```

which means you cannot seek in the file. Instead, open it for reading and writing:

```
$f = new SplFileObject('test.txt', 'r+');
```

They also say it in the [fseek documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php):

> If you have opened the file in append (a or a+) mode, any data you write to the file will always be appended, regardless of the file position, and the result of calling fseek() will be undefined.

Comment: Well... I changed mode but the file was truncated! According PHP official site: w mode: "Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and TRUNCATE THE FILE TO ZERO LENGTH. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it." I don't want truncate file, I want this result: "oneas"

Comment: OK when you are reading the docs... why don't you choose a different mode that doesn't truncate the file? It's right there on the same doc page.

Comment: e.g. "r+" does this: "Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file." I'll update my answer to this